# Are the Fable games' stories continuous?

Tags: fable-3, fable-series

I've played through Fable, and I own Fable 3, but I want to know if the story will still make sense if I skip Fable 2. Do all three have one continuous story, are they completely separate, or something in between? Are there things I won't understand in Fable 3 if I don't play Fable 2?

Please avoid spoilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The story of Fable is about the family of the hero from the first game. Each subsequent game is a continuation of that hero's family that comes into their own powers and finds their place in the world as they discover their abilities and stop some great evil that is currently threatening the world. While they all share the legacy of the family, you do not have to play the games in any specific order for lore purposes.

Comment: You will need to have played the first three games to fully understand the story of Theresa, that is explained by herself in Fable: The Journey. There are also some characters that appear in Fable II that reappear in Fable III, as well as some items, side stories, etc. Though it is not vital for the story plot, I recomend to play Fable II before Fable III.

Answer (score 2):

I played Fable II thoroughly, and later started Fable III when it came out.  As far as I could tell there wasn't really enough related to Fable II to really matter.  If you want my true opinion, play Fable II instead and forget about Fable III.  Fable III was awful by comparison.  Then again, I know that's not what you asked.

I don't think you'll have any real continuity problems if you skip Fable II.  I never played the first Fable but greatly enjoyed Fable II, and I think I heard that the first two are more connected.

Comment: personally i don't think either fable 2 or 3 was as good as the original. however each brought something new to the series, 2 being the first attempt at cooperative play via online as well as the dog for a companion. 3 further expanded on the online coop and actually got it right(not that minion trash you had to put up with as a player joining someone else's game in fable 2). 3 also made quite a few improvements in various aspects of the game that was added in 2.

Comment: I don't recall Fable II having any online coop.  Yes, there were online aspects, but you saw other players only as icons in the world and the only interaction was trading items.  It's not like you actually played side by side with other characters in the same game world.

Comment: My wife and I have been wanting to play the first Fable as we have heard it is good but haven't had a chance to try it.  I thought Fable III was awful, even for the short time I tried it.

Comment: no, fable 2 did have coop, it was just terrible, you literally played with your friend as a minion, not your hero. you may have had to have the person as a friend on xboxlive though to coop

Comment: Oh, I remember that now.  I actually thought that was only local, but I just checked and apparently coop was available online or offline.  I remember it sucked, though.

Comment: yep, that's why i still liked fable 3 over fable 2. At least in three you were actually playing your hero in all their glory, and you were able to wander around the zones without having to be in the same general area of the map.(was about the size of what you were able to see on your screen at any given time in fable 2)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8626/discussion-between-vertigoelectric-and-ravekner)

Answer (score 0):

they kind of have the same theme, but each is in a different time period. The only thing the same from each game that I can remember is the one narrating lady, at least from 2 to 3 (I don't remember if she was in the very first fable).

Comment: From the Fable Wiki site:  "Theresa is the immortal older sister of the Hero of Oakvale. Possessing prophetic powers due to her ancient bloodline, Theresa has a recurring role in all games as a guide to the Hero and is frequently referred to as "the Blind Seeress". "

Answer (score -1):

In Fable 2, in the beginning of the game you find a book that talks about the hero who destroyed Jack of Blades 500 years prior to your current time in Fable 2.  That hero is the hero from the first Fable game.  By the time Fable 2 takes place the guild has been destroyed and your character and your characters sibling is that last of the "hero blood line" that exists.  Teresa (the hooded woman in Fable 2) is the same Teresa from the first Fable game who is also in Fable 3.  Through some magical power (or something along those lines) she has lived to the time of Fable 2 and Fable 3.  There are small references throughout Fable 2 that connects to the first Fable and also through Fable 3 that connects to Fable 2.  At some point in Fable 2 if you purchase all the property in the game you will be crowned "King" of Albion. (Or queen)  Supposedly, its never happened to me but ive never bought all the property either.  When you play Fable 3, they commonly refer to "The Old Hero King" who died, which is the father of your character in Fable 3.  Fable 2 and Fable 3 are very close together as far as time frame whereas Fable 1 would be considered ancient history.